# 2 DCHP servers and 1 WDS server, same subnet

Tags: dhcp, wds, windows-server-2012-r2

I have DC1 hosting DCHP. DC2 also has DHCP although it is configured as a failover DHCP server. I have WDS installed on DC2. So I have DHCP and WDS on same server. I have tried all kinds of DHCP option 60, 66-67 on both DCHP servers. No matter what I do, I can't PXE boot from my client. I went as far as removing the failover on DC2 and stopping DHCP on DC2.  PXE boot works fine.  As soon as I re-enable DHCP as a failover on DC2, no more PXE boot.
MS Server 2012. Does anyone have any tips on how to configure this so WDS works AND I can keep my DHCP failover?

Comment: Is this Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: You should only need Options 66 and 67 to PXE boot. What exactly is happening when you "can't PXE boot"??

Comment: Sorry, I am not at that job. It's a part time that I have. The PC's will not get an ip address.  When I populate option 60, 66, 67 on DC1, the PCs gets an IP but then I get a dhcpproxy error 4101 (I can't remember the exact message) When I remove 66,67 - leaving only 60 populated, then no IP and no boot file loaded.

Comment: Server 2012 R2.  Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Are you specifying option 66 by FQDN or by IP address?